# Sound is low on 11.10 compared to Win 7

Tags: 11.10

I dual boot 11.10 64bit/ Windows 7 on my HP Pavilion DV 6700. I noticed that on 11.10 even when volume is at its maximum, the sound is REALLY low compared to Windows 7. What could be the cause or is it a bug?

Comment: I find it odd. I have here the same model and it works perfect. I have Windows XP and Ubuntu 11.10 32bit.

Comment: Really odd as max volume on Win 7 is too noisy but max volume on 11.10 seems like 50% on Win 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same model and works correctly. You might want to do 2 things:

1. ALSAMIXER

Open the terminal and type `alsamixer`. Press Enter and after the program opens type F5. Look for any volume bar that is low and is related to the sound volume.
[image]

2 Ubuntu Sound Settings

Click on the Sound Icon in the Top Panel. On the Sound menu that opens click on the Sound Settings option. Move the sound to 100% or more.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try opening a terminal and issuing the command:

alsamixer

Then make sure Master and PCM are up, then you can more finely control volume with gui controls.